# Getting column names in SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql

How can I access column's from SELECT, in my WHERE statement? I'm probably missing quotes. For context, this is in a controller, in Strapi CMS, which runs on a node.js server.

**Problem:**
Occurs at AND statement (mainly the first `st_geomfromtext` line):

```
const rawBuilder = strapi.connections.default.raw(
`
SELECT    
    locations.id as Location_ID,
    locations.Title as Location_Title,
    locations.Latitude as Location_Latitude,
    locations.Longitude as Location_Longitude,
    things.id,
    things.Title,
    things.Location
FROM locations
RIGHT JOIN things
ON locations.id = things.Location
WHERE things.Style = ` + ctx.query['Style.id'] + `
AND round(st_distance_sphere(
    st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(',locations.Longitude, ' ', locations.Latitude,')')),          
    st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(` + ctx.query.Longitude + ` ` + ctx.query.Latitude + `)'))
)) <= ` + 5000

)
```

**Test works:**
Just for fun, same as above, but just passed request variables for both st_geomfromtext lines, and the response works; no SQL error:

```
AND round(st_distance_sphere(
    st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(` + ctx.query.Longitude1 + ` ` + ctx.query.Latitude1 + `)')),          
    st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(` + ctx.query.Longitude2 + ` ` + ctx.query.Latitude2 + `)'))
)) <= ` + 5000
```

So as far as I can tell, the first `st_geomfromtext` line is the culprit, however it (the 1st line) works fine in a Go server... another clue that this is just a syntax problem.

Comment: Your RIGHT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. If you want real RIGHT JOIN result, move the locations conditions from WHERE to ON.

Comment: To access select list columns, wrap the select as a subquery, and you can then use the selected columns on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example in SQL Server that should help you resolve this.

Please try these steps:

1. Remove the "AND" statement from your where clause and save it somewhere
2. Add some filter criteria that will give you just few known locations
3. Add new output fields in your select criteria for each function so you will know what you are comparing.

   Select CONCAT('POINT(',locations.Longitude, ' ', locations.Latitude,')') from locations

   Select st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(',locations.Longitude, ' ', locations.Latitude,')')) from locations
   Note: the output to the geo functions this will probably look cryptic like 0xE6100000010C75931804564253C042CF66D5E7724340
4. Once the values line up the way you expect then add a new version of the where clause with the adjustments you have made.
5. Check the precision of the st_distance_sphere function. In SQL Server this is defaulted to meters.

Example in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE #locations (id INT, Title VARCHAR(50), Latitude DECIMAL(10,4), Longitude DECIMAL(10,4))
CREATE TABLE #things (id INT, Title VARCHAR(50), LocationId INT)

INSERT INTO #locations (id, Title, Latitude, Longitude) Values (1,'WH', 38.8977, -77.0365)
INSERT INTO #locations (id, Title, Latitude, Longitude) Values (2,'CB', 38.8899, -77.0091)
INSERT INTO #things (id, Title, LocationId) Values (100,'White House',1)
INSERT INTO #things (id, Title, LocationId) Values (101,'United States Capitol',2)

--My Location at the Washington Monument
DECLARE @myLat DECIMAL(10,4) = 38.8895;
DECLARE @myLong DECIMAL(10,4) = -77.0353

SELECT    
    loc.id as Location_ID,
    loc.Title as Location_Title,
    loc.Latitude as Location_Latitude,
    loc.Longitude as Location_Longitude,
    th.id,
    th.Title,
    th.LocationId,
    geometry::STGeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',loc.Longitude, ' ', loc.Latitude,')'),4326) as ItemPoint,
    geometry::STGeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',@myLat,' ',@myLong,')'),4326) as MyPoint,
    geometry::STGeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',loc.Longitude, ' ', loc.Latitude,')'),4326).STDistance(geometry::STGeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',@myLat,' ',@myLong,')'),4326))
FROM #locations loc
RIGHT JOIN #things th ON loc.id = th.LocationId

DROP TABLE #locations
DROP TABLE #things
```